# Capture an individual Cell of a Column in GNU Bash 4.2.46(2)

Tags: bash

I am trying to capture individual cells of a multi-row and multi-column file using Bash scripting.  I need to do this with pure Bash.  My assignment will not allow me to use tcl, awk, sed, perl, python, etc.  This is a part of a much bigger function-- the only hiccup is this one line of code.

I wrote and tested my below script on GNU Bash 4.4.19(1) and it works!  Problem is the school server which is where this will be graded is using GNU Bash 4.2.46(2).  The script does not work on the school server.

It outputs the cell in Row 1, Column 1 of a file called table.  Each column is separated with tabs.  Each row is created with a newline.

```
cat table | cut -f 1 -d$'\n' | cut -f 1 > outputFile
```

The above code does not work on Bash 4.2.46(2).  It will output the first column.  But not the individual cell which is what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't think the bash version will make a difference since you're not using any new shell features.

Comment: `cut -f 1 -d$'\n'` is strange. If you just want the first line use `head -1`.

Comment: The bash version did make a difference for some reason.  I copied and pasted the same exact code from one to another and I have the above results.

Comment: That second command in the pipeline isn't doing anything.  cut processes line by line, so it should never see a newline to split on.  The third command is going to pull the 1st field of a tab delimited file.  Is your file tab delimited?  If not, here is an example for pipe delimited: `cut -d'|' -f1 table > outputFile`

Comment: It might be the version of `cut` that matters, or the input might be different. But the *bash* version shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: You're allowed to use cat and cut but not awk? I'd think "pure bash" means built ins only, no external programs of any kind.

Comment: Awk is a Turing complete programming language. That's probably why it's disallowed.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using pure Bash, you are calling external programs like cat, tail and head.
The distinction between these and sed or awk out of the perspective of your assignment is not described in your post.

I hope you actually know your requirements, as your current solution does not qualify as Bash-only.

This would be a solution in pure Bash:

```
read line < table; [[ $line =~ ^[^$'\t']* ]];  printf "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" > outputFile
```

Also, the version of Bash has nothing to do with how tail or cat work, since they are separate programs, just like bash itself.
The issue is probably that the school server has older versions of mostly everything.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments and suggestions I received for this post along with trial-and-error playing around, I have opted to use the following format which allows me to select the row with the head command, get one listing with the tail, and then the column number with cut:

```
cat table | head -n 1 | tail -n 1 | cut -f1 > outputFile
```

I chose to use cut in case I wanted a different column.  I needed this for a loop.

I also stand corrected.  The solution was not "pure bash."  My assignment did allow cat, head, tail, and cut.  But the other languages such as sed, awk, etc. were not allowed.

Thanks everyone for the input.  This has been a most edifying experience for a beginner.

Comment: You can get rid of `cat` and `tail`: `head -1 table | cut -f1`.